# I can't get enumerate to print lowercase roman numerals

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

With `enumerate` or `enumitem` (not both together), every time I expect a lowercase numeral, I get a small uppercase.

---

### Example with i:

```
\usepackage{enumerate}            \usepackage{enumitem}
...                               ...
\begin{enumerate}[i]         OR   \begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*}]
    \item \emph{Compart...}           \item \emph{Compart...}
\end{enumerate}                   \end{enumerate}
...                               ...
```

[image: small]

---

### Example with I:

```
\usepackage{enumerate}            \usepackage{enumitem}
...                               ...
\begin{enumerate}[I]         OR   \begin{enumerate}[label={\Roman*}]
    \item \emph{Compart...}           \item \emph{Compart...}
\end{enumerate}                   \end{enumerate}
...                               ...
```

[image: big]

Comment: I see a lower case `i`. You should not load both packages -- if you want to emulate `enumerate` features with `enumitem`, use `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` alone. If this does not fix your issue, post a compilable, full document, not just disrupted code

Comment: The 'long' form for `enumitem` is `label={\roman*}`.

Comment: Are you perhaps using both [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) *and* [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)?

Comment: Hi, as I tell in the question, I don't use both, I use  `enumerate` **OR** (xor) `enumitem`, with `[i]` or `[label={\roman*}]` respectively

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I actually see a difference between using `[i]` and `[I]`, in the first case, the uppercase "I" is printed in a smaller size than using `I`, but still being uppercase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue only if `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` is stated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]
\item Primero
\item Segundo
\item Tercero
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Fix

Add the `es-lcroman` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]
\item Primero
\item Segundo
\item Tercero
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pavarotti is to the Opera like you to latex! I haven't told anything about babel but you guessed it! Did you spy my computer? hahah. Thanks a lot, it works like a charm

Comment: @onlycparra Educated guess and experience. `;-)`