# How to enumerate a list in the format i), ii), iii) instead of I), II), III)

Tags: lists, enumerate, roman-numerals

I like to use different formats for my list: a), b), c); 1), 2), 3); i), ii), iii) and I know I can do this with the package enumerate, writing [a)] or [1)] or [i)]. However, writing

```
\begin{enumerate}[i)]
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

or

```
\begin{enumerate}[I)]
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

In both cases i receive the same format: I), II), III), being the only difference the size. I prefer lowercase instead of capital letters.

[image]

I have even tried the labels \roman and \Roman, and I and I keep receiving the same format.

In the preamble I have tried with

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

or

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of showing small fragments of code, please edit your question to show a compilable document that produces the incorrect output you're describing. Using the `enumerate` package and `\begin{enumerate}[i)]` should give you lower case Roman numerals; if it's not, you need to show us exactly what you're doing. I suspect you're loading `babel` with the `spanish` option, and it's turning your lower case roman into small caps.

Comment: With `enumitem` using `\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]` should do.

Comment: @Skillmon Not if `spanish` is loaded with no other `babel` options. But we need to see actual code to be sure.

Comment: If you use `spanish` babel, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355782/i-cant-get-enumerate-to-print-lowercase-roman-numerals/355797#355797

Comment: Please confirm that your document loads the `babel` option with the language option `spanish` (or, possibly, `catalan`).

Comment: The problem was the language spanish, and adding the option of es-lcroman have solved the problem. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: For future, you could have saved everyone some time if you had included a minimal document that reproduced the problem. Then we wouldn't have to have guessed at what you were doing.  So for future questions, please always include a minimal compilable document that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Is @Alan Munn suspicion is correct, than @egreg [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355782/i-cant-get-enumerate-to-print-lowercase-roman-numerals/355797#355797) solve your problem. Its MWE adopted to your question can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}  % observe added "es-lcroman"
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[i)]
\item Primero
\item Segundo
\item Tercero
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, similar problems happens also at many other (non english)  languages.

Comment: If you're going to turn my comments into answers and then copy another answer at least spell my name correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a spanish speaker and that was the problem. That option of "es-lcroman" have solved my problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn, sorry for wrong spelling your name (corrected now). If you will write answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: I don't really care because the question should be closed as a duplicate anyway. But if people are actively commenting on an answer asking for more information, I don't think it's very polite to turn their comments into an answer without waiting until the information requested has been given and they've had an opportunity to add an answer themselves.

Comment: @Zarko there was never a need for your answer if this is a duplicate...

Comment: @Skillmon, unfortunately I was to late for delete it.

Comment: @Vázquez, since your answer is duplicate, I like to delete mine. That I can do only if you remove your acceptation. Please, do this asap.

Comment: @Zarko I've undone your edit. There is no need to delete the answer. But going forward, don't takes answers from from people's comments and don't repeat a duplicate answer in a new answer. You've been around long enough to know this.